# Can I use the word 'boss' as a verb?

Tags: word-choice

Like, for example, could I use 'to boss' instead of 'to dominate/to command' in a phrase.

Would people understand the meaning?
Just would like to know if it's possible to use in a conversation, informal talking, for example.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that questions which can be answered by using a dictionary or other conventional reference are off-topic here. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance about how this site works. The short answer is yes: *[boss](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/boss), verb with object: Give (someone) orders in a domineering manner* (ODO)

Comment: Yes, I researched a lot this question, but I only could find 'to boss around', and my question was if I could use only 'to boss' as a verb alone itself.

Comment: That is not the question you asked. A question needs to explain exactly what you are seeking, and indicate the research you have attempted, as explained in the [help]. Please [edit the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/319628/edit) to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can, as generally in football(Soccer),we often say that "Mesut Ozil bossed midfield with his finest touches on and off the ball". It means his physical strength and ability on ball, out-muscled others.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Men claim women love to boss them around.

"She ​waved her ​friend over as if bossing around a ​maid."

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boss-around-someone

"He’s used to bossing his little brother around."

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/boss_2

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

"She liked to boss me because she liked it when I bossed her.